# Silverlight Page in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight-5.0

I am using Silverlight code sharing with WPF .

Silverlight pages are(navigation:Page) but in WPF there is only Page so i am getting error.

Is it possible to use Silverlight Page in WPF.

[image]

Comment: It won't work as SL uses a different runtime than WPF, but the question is why would you want to do this? There are loads of controls in WPF that perform essentially the same task - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you`re using same elements in WPF and Silverlight projects, then the better approach is to share page content, not page itself.

Comment: i want to use same page in both Silverlight and WPf.

Comment: I am solve this problem with Creating a Custom Control Inherit from Page. now Page will work in Silverlight and WPF Application. I don't now this way is proper or not please give Suggestions i Replace this code (navigation:Page from Silverlight and using my Custom Control)